# Eclipse Compare Editor: difference between the 'next difference' and 'next change' buttons?

Tags: eclipse

A simple question today...

In the Eclipse compare editor (right click file - compare with...) what is the difference between the 'next difference' and 'next change' buttons? They seem to do exactly the same thing.

Its bugging me!

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [Help page for the "compare editor"](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-25.htm) states:

> - A change is a portion of text that has been modified within the line, and
> - the difference is a section of file consisting of one or more lines, and can contain many changes.
>
> Differences are marked with blue color, changes with red.

[image: Eclipse compare Editor]

So if each of the differences are only *one* change within *one* line each time... then yes, changes and differences will match exactly.